# Can I set different content for blank pages using @page?

Tags: css, printing, pdf-generation

I'm using @page:blank to style blank pages that get added to a pdf for print, I'm having issues  creating different styles based on classes that generated these blank pages. is there a way to accomplish this?

```css
/* this class adds a blank page when printing*/
.page-break {
      page-break-before:right;
 }   

/* I'm currently adding content to the top center header of all blank pages like this */
@page:blank { 
    @top-center {
        content: "this page intentionally left blank"
     }
 }

/* I'm now trying to split into two languages, I tried this: */
.english-blank,  .spanish-blank {
      page-break-before:right;
 }   
 
 .english-blank @page:blank { 
    @top-center {
        content: "this page intentionally left blank"
     }
 }
 
.spanish-blank @page:blank  {
    @top-center {
        content: "esta página se dejó en blanco intencionalmente"
     }
}

/* I also tried this: */
.english-blank {
    page-break-before:right;
    page: english;
}
.spanish-blank {
    page-break-before:right;
    page: spanish;
}

@page english:blank {
    @top-center {
        content: "this page intentionally left blank"
     }
}

@page spanish:blank {
    @top-center {
        content: "esta página se dejó en blanco intencionalmente"
     }
}
```